R Code: Scrape ETF summary stats from Yahoo Finance
I seek to scrape ETF summary stats from Yahoo finance.  For example, the page link is https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/IVV.  Below the graph, is the table to scrape and the key fields are NAV, PE Ratio TTM, yield, beta and expense ratio. I previously used the rvest package as follows, but that is no longer working as the page structure has changed
ticker <- "IVV"
url <- paste0("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/",ticker)
df <- url %>%
      read_html() %>%
      html_table() %>%
      map_df(bind_cols) %>%
      as_tibble()

Any help appreciated

It looks like there is no longer a table element in that link, as the info you're after is now contained in list elements. I have tweaked the code to capture the label and values from each list element.
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

ticker <- "IVV"
url <- paste0("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/",ticker)

ivv_html <- read_html(url)

node_txt <- ".svelte-tx3nkj" # This contains "table" info of interest

df <- ivv_html %>% 
  html_nodes(paste0(".container", node_txt)) %>%
  map_dfr(~{
    tibble(
      label = html_nodes(.x, paste0(".label", node_txt)) %>% 
        html_text(trim = TRUE)
      ,value = html_nodes(.x, paste0(".value", node_txt)) %>% 
        html_text(trim = TRUE)
    )
  })

df %>% 
  filter(label %in% c("NAV", "PE Ratio (TTM)", "Yield", "Beta (5Y Monthly)", "Expense Ratio (net)"))

# A tibble: 5 × 2
  label               value 
  <chr>               <chr> 
1 NAV                 519.85
2 PE Ratio (TTM)      26.22 
3 Yield               1.37% 
4 Beta (5Y Monthly)   1.00  
5 Expense Ratio (net) 0.03% 

Adding .container class will limit the info you're after to just the "table" located under the chart, otherwise all info tagged with the class .svelte-tx3nkj from that page will be extracted.

UPD 2024-08-23, following HTML structure change:
node_txt <- "yf-tx3nkj"

ivv_html %>% 
  html_nodes(paste0("ul.", node_txt)) %>% 
  html_nodes(paste0(".", node_txt)) %>% 
  map(~{
    tibble(
      label = html_nodes(.x, paste0(".label.", node_txt)) %>% 
        html_text(trim = TRUE)
      ,value = html_nodes(.x, paste0(".value.", node_txt)) %>%
        html_text(trim = TRUE)
    )
  }) %>% 
  list_rbind()

df %>% 
  filter(label %in% c("NAV", "PE Ratio (TTM)", "Yield", "Beta (5Y Monthly)", "Expense Ratio (net)"))


No worries, if the answer works for you please accept the answer so that the question can be marked and others can find the answer useful

Sactyr - Looks like the HTML page structure has changed as I cant locate the node_txt with the data and the code is returning an empty dataframe. Any insight to retrieve the data?

@BradHorn yea it looks like both node_txt and rest of the HTML changed. I have updated my answer above to include the changes. Also changed map_dfr to map since map_dfr seems to have been superseded.
